# Einstein (Wave) Analytics asset became unavailable after Namespace Prefix creation!

Tags: managed-package, einstein-analytics, namespace

**Description:**

We are using Einstein Analytics to create more insight on products our customers have, this requires creation of Einstein Analytics dataflows, datasets, dashboards and apps.

We embed the dashboards under the relevant lightning page with filters. For distributing the Einstein Analytics solutions, we need to distribute them with Extension Packages.

Using 'Package Manager', we packaged the Einstein Application, Dataflow, Dataset, Dashboard and relevant custom fields into an extension package and added a namespace prefix.

**Problem:**

After this step, the Einstein Analytics dashboards didn't appear in the lightning pages. When we edit the lightning page, we see a warning as

> 'This Wave Analytics asset is currently unavailable. An asset is
>   unavailable: if it was deleted, it doesn't exist, you don't have
>   access to it, or we're getting it ready.'

[image: select wave dashboard to add to the lightning page]

For the dashboards embedded in the page, we receive

> 'Invalid Component'

error.

[image: Wave Dashboard - Invalid Component]

We checked the permission sets and users access to Einstein Analytics apps, everything seems ok, also everything in Einstein Analytics app seems to be fine.

**Question:**

Did you ever experience something like this? If yes, please give us a hand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally we have a known issue!

[**Please follow the link and click "This affects you."**](http://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000019QasQAE)